# Using the rule of 55

Tags: united-states, 401k, retirement-plan, withdrawal

If I wanted to withdraw $50k out of my 401(k) using the rule of 55, How much more will I have to pay to get that amount. Will I have to pay the 20% federal tax and the 10% early withdrawal penalty and state taxes?

Comment: No penalty, but normal income tax for fed and state.

Comment: Do you know what tax brackets you are in for both federal and state? The tax is not a set percentage for either - it is counted as though it were "normal" income.